# How to draw a picture whose name corresponds to an int?

Tags: python-3.x

I have made a Pokedex in Python and I want to draw a picture of the right Pokémon. Drawing a picture is no problem, but drawing the correct one is harder. I have 800+ images of Pokemon that are named after their Pokedex number (For example, Bulbasaur is the first Pokemon in the Pokedex and thus has a number 1, and it's picture is named '1.gif').

How can I draw the picture that corresponds to the number that is searched for?

I know that coding 800+ if statements is way too complicated and that this can be done easier, I just don't know how.

This is the code I'm using to draw a picture. At this moment, it only draws the picture of Bulbasaur.

```
pic = Image(Point(350, 410), "1.gif")
pic.draw(win)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you just create a function which takes as an argument the number and concatenates it to the string ".gif"?

Comment: String formatting is useful as well such as `f"{my_int}.gif"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function were born to avoid using an infinite number of `if` statements!

```
def drawPokemon(pokedex_num):
    pic = Image(Point(350, 410), str(pokedex_num) + ".gif")
    pic.draw(win)
```